# Getting socket.io, express & node-http2 to communicate though HTTP/2

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, http2

I wrote a Web Socket server using socket.io, node-http2 and express in Node.js. The server works as intended, except for the fact that according to Chrome's DevTools socket.io's negotiation requests go through HTTP/1.1 (shown below). The "Protocol" column should be displaying `h2` if the request was sent using HTTP/2.

> [image]

This only happens in Chrome, other browsers use the correct protocol.

The server code (shortened):

```
var PORT = 8667,
    config = require('./config'),
    socketioServer = require('socket.io'),
    app = express(),
    https = require('http2'),
    cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors(function(req, callback){
    var corsOptions = { origin: false };
    if (/^https:\/\/mlpvc-rr\.lc/.test(req.header('Origin')))
        corsOptions.origin = true;
    callback(null, corsOptions);
}));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendStatus(403);
});

var server = https.createServer({
    cert: fs.readFileSync(config.SSL_CERT),
    key: fs.readFileSync(config.SSL_KEY),
}, app);
server.listen(PORT);
var io = socketioServer.listen(server);
// ...
```

Browser connection code:

```
var conn = io('https://ws.'+location.hostname+':8667/', { reconnectionDelay: 5000 });
conn.on('connect', function(){
    console.log('[WS] Connected');
});
conn.on('disconnect',function(){
    console.log('[WS] Disconnected');
});
```

Output of [testssl.sh](https://testssl.sh/):

> [image]

What do I need to change to make the socket.io requests go through HTTP/2?

Comment: Hi. Can you get me a complete example? I would love to take a closer look to it. At first sight it seems something to do with websockets (which socket.io uses and which are not supported by HTTP/2) but the requests you show *seem* to be ordinary Ajax...

Comment: @dsign The server is open-sourced at https://github.com/ponydevs/MLPVC-WS

Comment: Which SSL library are you using (openssl?) and which version and does it support ALPN? https://ma.ttias.be/day-google-chrome-disables-http2-nearly-everyone-may-31st-2016/

Comment: @BazzaDP I have no idea about either, I just use whatever `npm install` installs by default. The `config.*` variables are simply strings pointing to specific SSL key/crt files.

Comment: Is it public facing? If so use https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest to test for this. If not try https://testssl.sh which does a lot of the same tests but can be run locally.

Comment: @BazzaDP When I try to check I get the error `Ports other than 443 not supported`. I can't use testssl.sh because I develop on Windows, but the same problem can be observed both on my development machine and in production.

Comment: Yeah need to use testssl.sh then instead. Also does it work with h2 in other browsers (e.g. Opera?)? Also do you have any anti-virus software intercepting your traffic which often downgrades you to http/1.1

Comment: @BazzaDP Regular website traffic routed though CloudFlare and nginx come through as `h2`, it's only the negotiation requests socket.io makes to it's own server that are not HTTP/2.

Comment: ALPN not offered so won't work in Chrome as per article above. Try Opera or Firefox and see if it uses h2 there to confirm.

Comment: @BazzaDP Firefox indeed marks negotiation requests as HTTP/2. The question of how to make it go through that on Chrome still remains, though.

Comment: I didn't think express supported http2 yet? So even if you did manage to fix this issue, it would just crash instead.

Comment: @Ashley It didn't crash when the client managed to connect on Firefox, so evidently it supports it somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in comments Chrome has recently stopped allowing the older NPN negotiation for HTTP/2 and insists on the newer ALPN protocol instead. See this article for more info: https://ma.ttias.be/day-google-chrome-disables-http2-nearly-everyone-may-31st-2016/

So you basically need Node.js to support ALPN which it looks as has only been added in v5 so far: https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/2564 . An alternative would be to route your NodeJs calls through a webserver which is easier to upgrade OpenSSL (e.g. Nginx or Apache) to support HTTP/2 over ALPN.

You confirmed this was the issue by using the [testssl.sh](https://testssl.sh) program which confirmed no ALPN support and the fact Firefox uses HTTP/2.

Comment: My server is running on Node.js version 4.4.7 which (according to [this page](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/vulnerability/openssl-march-2016/)) comes with OpenSSL 1.0.2 by default, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Looks to me like ALPN only works in Node 5: https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/2564. Looks like there was talk to back port it to v4 but not completed: https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/5983

Comment: Thank you for the info, I'll just wait until v6 hits LTS then.

Answer (score 3):

A little bit late but with Express4 and [Spdy](https://github.com/spdy-http2/node-spdy) ([npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/spdy)) is working great.

bin/www:

```
var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('gg:server');
var spdy = require('spdy');
var fs = require('fs');
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/server.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/server.crt')
}
var server = spdy.createServer(options, app);
var io = app.io
io.attach(server);
server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);
...
```

app.js:

```
...
var app = express();
var io = app.io = require('socket.io')();
...
```

client screenshot:
[image]