# Socket.io perpetual disconnection on HTTP 2 due to missing Keep-Alive headers

Tags: websocket, socket.io

After having developed my application in an unsecured context using HTTP 1.1, I have now deployed it to a HTTP 2 server using HTTPS. All fine and dandy. For 30 seconds... :)

After that, the socket disconnects and connects again. And again. And again.

[image]

What I saw missing from the server response are the `Connection: keep-alive` and `Keep-Alive: timeout=5` headers that I get on my HTTP 1.1 server. The code is absolutely identical and communication does work just fine.

I suppose socket.io has some smart way of working over HTTP 2 but I couldn't find anything about this in the documentation.

It's also interesting that the client DOES request the keep-alive header, despite it running on HTTP 2. But alas, nothing is returned and the socket disconnects :(

[image]

I noticed somebody tried using SPDY via Express:

[Getting socket.io, express & node-http2 to communicate though HTTP/2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38662677/getting-socket-io-express-node-http2-to-communicate-though-http-2)

I would consider this as a possible solution, but I would like this to work without SPDY as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After encountering the EXACT same issue when using the WebSocket object in the browser, I dug deeper and found this in the documentation of the Google Load Balancer service we're using:

The timeout for a WebSocket connection depends on the configurable backend service timeout of the load balancer, which is **30 seconds** by default. This timeout applies to WebSocket connections regardless of whether they are in use. For more information about the backend service timeout and how to configure it, see Timeouts and retries.

https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https?fbclid=IwAR2Qugtlyvd05VteGWk2RCevebUJrHTHyW9RHAwYiPxudM6qOovaa2Zdqpk

Check this article for more info about how to config your Load Balancer to correctly handle WebSockets:

https://medium.com/johnjjung/how-to-use-gcp-loadbalancer-with-websockets-on-kubernetes-using-services-ingresses-and-backend-16a5565e4702